# dvc push: local variable referenced before assigment

Tags: git, dvc

Error while pushing files to DVC:

```
dvc push
ERROR: unexpected error - local variable 'paths' referenced before assignment                                                 

Having any troubles? Hit us up at https://dvc.org/support, we are always happy to help!
```

Previously i add files to /app/data directory in my project container and push data.dvc to git:

```
dvc add /app/data                                                                             
100% Adding...|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████|1/1 [00:04,  4.62s/file]
git add data.dvc                                                                              
git commit -m 'Add experiment data to dvc'                                                    
[test 3f0b5de] Add experiment data to dvc                                                                                     
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

How can i fix that to push data correctly?

For information:

```
dvc version
DVC version: 2.42.0 (pip)
---------------------------------
Platform: Python 3.8.13 on Linux-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5
Subprojects:
        dvc_data = 0.34.0
        dvc_objects = 0.18.1
        dvc_render = 0.0.17
        dvc_task = 0.1.11
        dvclive = 2.0.2
        scmrepo = 0.1.6
Supports:
        http (aiohttp = 3.8.4, aiohttp-retry = 2.8.3),
        https (aiohttp = 3.8.4, aiohttp-retry = 2.8.3),
        s3 (s3fs = 2023.6.0, boto3 = 1.26.76)
Cache types: 
Cache directory: overlay on overlay
Caches: local
Remotes: s3, s3
Workspace directory: overlay on overlay
Repo: dvc, git
```

Comment: https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/8863 Found in https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues?q=is%3Aissue+push%3A+unexpected+error+-+local+variable+%27paths%27+referenced+before+assignment